# send respective email of user in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on ajax the problem i am facing is i have two functions, first one to get data through ajax for users from server. the data recieved have email along with all other data of each user. the emails for every user is saved in a variable lets suppose we have user A and his email is user@A.com and another user B that have email user@b.com and same for user c and so on if more users. below is the code

```
$(response).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").each(function(i, span) {
    employee_email = $(span).text();
```

remember employee_email is a global variable

now the second function that is for email sending through ajax and the url contain the email as a parameter.the send email function is called through button click and every user record have its own button.  the problem is here if i click the button that is below the user A so the parameter in url should be user@A.com and if button below record of user B is clicked then parameter should be user@B.com and same for c and so on if user exist. below is the code for it.But in my case it only send email to the last email that is saved in employee_email. so i am unable to make logic for it so need you help. if possible please elaborate your answer so that i could understand and could handle such situations by myself in future.

```
function sendEmail(){

if(flag)
{
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "send_email.php?"+employee_email,
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
            $("#email_responses").html();
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#email_responses").html('error occured');
        }
    });
}
else
    alert('Sending email is unavailable currently. PLease try after some time.');
}
```

here is the code for button that appears below each user.

```
<div class="send_email_notification">
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" onClick="sendEmail();">
</div>
```

Comment: every thing is very clear then why down vote

Answer (score 0):

Some advice to help you solve your problem:

1 - Avoid using global variables

In your first code, you iterate over all the span to set the value of your global variable. At the end of your loop, this global variable will only have the last email. That is probably the origin of your problem.

2 - One possible solution

There are different solutions to your problem. Here is one: when the button is clicked, retrieve the selected email with some jquery path from the clicked button. For example, if your html is:

```
<div>
  <span class="email">user@domain.com</span>
  <div class="send_email_notification">
     <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In your javascript, you could get the selected email with this query:

```
function sendEmail(event) {
   var target = event.currentTarget;
   var email = $(target).parent().parent().find(".email").text();
   // and so on...
 }

 $('.send_email_notification input').on('click', sendEmail);
```

Note: you should also avoid the usage of onClick attribute in html elements. A more modern approach is to separate the javascript from the html code: that's why i removed it from my html version of your code.

Comment: thnks for your reply back but what is currentTarget here

Comment: currentTarget should be the element where the user clicked on. In this case, the input[submit] element.